# Engine Cranks But Won't Start, Tachometer Stuck at Zero

Tags: hyundai, accent, crankshaft-position-sensor

My 2010 Hyundai Accent has been having starting issues recently. Occasionally it will crank but not start. Usually I can get it to start by cranking it a few times. One time it never started, and eventually my battery died from repeated cranking. I had to get it towed home. A few days before this happened I noticed that my tachometer was at zero while driving on the highway. I only noticed this once, and the next time I started the car, the tach was working as normal. The car did have a check engine code, but I have no record of it, and it seems to have disappeared. (It looks like it was cleared, but neither my friend or I recall clearing it) The code did lead us to look into the crankshaft position sensor. My friend thinks it was either P0336 or P0338. I the sensor , then realized that I needed to clean a bunch of road grit from around the hole, so I wiped the sensor off and reinstalled it so as to avoid getting the grit into the engine. Just for the fun of it, I cranked the engine and it started right up. My friend tested the sensor with his multimeter and the readings were within spec. Any thoughts on this?

Also, I don't think this is related, but I'll throw it in here just in case... The engine has developed a loud tapping noise, which you can hear by playing the videos in [this album](https://photos.app.goo.gl/bCqbm4RdGVdeF63W8).

Answer (score 1):

If it is consistently starting and running now, I'd suggest you not look a gift horse in the mouth. It sure sounds like the sensor was not sending a signal, or possibly a signal the ECU couldn't understand. That could be from the grime you cleaned of or whatever. My suggestion to you is to buy a backup sensor to have on hand (ie: in the car) for when it does go out. I would bet that may be sooner rather than later. Any which way, it'd be good insurance to have on hand. Since you've already removed it once, you have the knowhow and it's probably something you could do in a parking lot. Your clue of the tach showing nothing is a dead giveaway to me something with the sensor had gone wrong.

As far as the ticking noise. That is very noisy. Is the oil topped off? If low it could be making noises like that. When was the last time you had the oil changed? Dirty oil can make for a noisy engine. Are you using the manufacturer's recommended oil weight? Using the wrong weight of oil can cause issues as well. If the noise doesn't stop, there may be more serious issues with the engine.

Comment: I went ahead and replaced the crankshaft position sensor. It started with no issues 10 times in a row in my driveway. Hopefully it keeps working as I start driving it around again!

Comment: Also, I started a new question for the tapping noise here: https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/95000/what-is-this-tapping-noise-coming-from-my-engine.