# What is this tapping noise coming from my engine?

Tags: engine

I have a 2010 Hyundai Accent that recently developed a loud tapping noise in the engine area.

Here's a link with two videos so you can hear the noise:
https://photos.app.goo.gl/bCqbm4RdGVdeF63W8

I don't know if this is relevant, but I have been asked if I changed the oil... About 9 months before the noise started, when I did my last oil change, I added the amount specified in the owner's manual. When I checked the dipstick, it was over full. I stupidly left it that way and drove it about 8 or 10 thousand miles. I just changed the oil again. I let the old oil drain for 30-45 minutes. (The old oil was still overfull at this point) I used the recommended oil weight. I also added a bit less oil (probably 1/4-1/2 quart less than specified)  When I checked the dipstick, it was overfull again. (1/8-1/4" over the full mark) I haven't started driving it since the oil change, and I have noticed in another car that it may take a few miles for the extra engine noise that results in low oil to go away. However, when I start it up, the noise is just as loud as before.

I did a little hunting around with my stethoscope and noticed that the noise is probably the loudest when I place it on the fuel injectors, but it's also pretty loud in various other places as well.

Any ideas as to where I should start looking or how to diagnose this?